# Is there a free default limit for the Google App Engine Socket API?

Tags: google-app-engine, cost

I'm calling a URL to get json data from another web site in my Google App Engine application. Then i received bellow message.

> The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has
>   been enabled in the admin console

So I decided to enable billing, but I have a question: For [Mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail), we can send 100 messages for a day for free. Is there any similar free default limit for Socket API ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google App Engine documents for their API's, such as [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) for Java and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/) for Go:

> Sockets are only available for paid apps, and traffic from sockets is billed as outgoing     bandwidth.